# Can't edit style of html element injected with Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm curently building a chrome extension that injects some HTML in currents tab with Ajax.

Extension append a `<div>` to body and I'm now trying to edit it in javascript : I want it to "follow" user cursor => so I need to edit `top`, `left`, `width`, and `height`.

I don't manage to do it. I've tryed :

1)

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').style.top = myvalue + "px";
```

And get the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'top' of undefined
```

undefined seems to be "style" because I manage to get my node when I do : `console.log(document.getElementById('mydiv'));`

2)

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').setAttribute('style', 'top:' + myvalue + 'px;');
```

I manage to actually write this attribute in the tag, but for some reason my `<div>` don't care and remain at it's position :/

I've checked the following :

- body is `position:relative;`
- mydiv is `position:absolute;`
- manually append a div and edit it actually works

My inkling is myDiv is kind of instanciated due to the Ajax request.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you put a fiddle for this?

Comment: No idea how to provide a fiddle :
I use XHR with chrome.extension.getURL method to get my html file in which I select and inject a specific element into the user active tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finaly detect where the problem was :

I injected my node in the DOM as a node type `text/xml`
No way to style such an element...

Fixed by changing this to `text/html` when calling the `parseFromString()` method